# Meteor : ReferenceError: Kadira is not defined

Tags: meteor

I tried to install Kadira on a meteor application.

```
mrt add kadira
```

Ok

```
Kadira.connect('<appId>', '<appSecret>')
```

Ok

But, this is the error I have :

```
app/server/kadira.js:7
        console.log( Kadira );
                     ^
ReferenceError: Kadira is not defined
    at app/server/kadira.js:7:16
    at null._onTimeout (packages/underscore/underscore.js:673)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

And I don't understand how this is possible.

I checked the package and it exports the namespace as it should :

```
Package.on_use(function(api) {
    configurePackage(api);
    api.export(['Kadira']);
});
```

Comment: also do `meteor add kadira`

Comment: returned `Kadira: no such package`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteorite can sometimes be a little quirky.

1. Check your smart.json to see if it contains kadira
2. Check .meteor/packages to see if it contains kadira, if not add it.
3. Delete smart.lock and run `mrt install` once more.

Comment: smart.json ends with `"kadira": {}`, packages ends with `kadira`. I tried to delete & install and it worked !

Comment: @fabien Meteorite is a bit buggy in my experience. So when in doubt delete smart.lock and run `mrt install` once more. In meteor 0.9 things will probaply get better with meteor build in packaging. New packaging explained: https://meteor.hackpad.com/Getting-Started-With-Unipackage-IOckQBQgXaQ